# How to grind into concrete ( not core drill )

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, concrete

I have a very specific and weird task I need to accomplish.

I have a concrete wall that I need to get samples of the concrete dust to grind and get them tested, i plan on using a plunge router with a vacuum collar type setup with a grinding head of some sort ... problems are

- needs to be in-situ ( i can't do a standard core then chop it up )
- I can only find one grinding head that appears to do what i need https://i.stack.imgur.com/52mVo.png
- needs to be about 50-70mm diameter sample area and not miss any of each "layer"
- i need to do this about 50 times and i'm not sure a vacuum bezel head will last long?
- i need to drill in 0.5mm increments each sample of the dust

i thought id check and see if anyone else has an idea of an easier way I could accomplish this! Surely i'm not the only one who has encountered something like this.

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like a drill with a drill bit...

Comment: @SolarMike concrete drill bit's have a tapered end... i need to be going in depths of 0.5mm exactly not slightly more in the center compared to the outside ....

Comment: Re-grind a spade bit...

Comment: Drill out a core, then make saw cuts (like partial slices) using a thin blade. if you cut from various points you may be able to get the "definition" you require.

Comment: @SolarMike see first bullet point

Comment: First bullet point may be incorrect.... a core can be done in-situ...  what is a "standard" core? 4", 6" ...

Comment: What exactly are you testing, and why are you testing it? The idea of doing anything with concrete at 0.5mm resolution seems downright insane. Is this for an academic paper or something?

Comment: @SolarMike i realize i could do a core.. but i cannot for this particular task.

Comment: @Wasabi its to do with nordtest 443 standards